# Convert .dwg in mm to GIS

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, dwg

I have a dwg file containing some polylines that is georeferenced in UTM coordinates, but unfortunately has been converted to mm instead of metres, so has 3 extra digits on each x and y point. Is there a way to move the decimal place back by 3 and convert to GIS format? I'm using FME.

Comment: Please post your edited Question (with the solution) as an answer

Comment: Thanks but can't post an answer as it is on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the 'Scaler' transformer in FME. This allows you to 'scale' geometry by multiplying by a number (in this case I multiplied by 0.001 to get metres from mm). There may be a better way to change the scale in the original CAD drawing but for me as a mainly GIS user this was the easiest solution.

[image: Scaler]